# How to open a raw file in Camera Raw full size rather than cropped to in-camera aspect ratio?

Tags: raw, image-processing, adobe-camera-raw, aspect-ratio

On a recent photography holiday I took a number of photographs using the in camera option to change the image size to, for example, 16 x 9. The native image size of the camera is 4:3.

I transferred the images to an Epson-7000 viewer. The viewer shows the JPEGS in the selected image aspect, but the RAW files appear in 4:3. Some of the images were incorrectly cropped in the camera and I would like to correct this in Photoshop. However, when I open the RAW files in Camera Raw, I see the cropped versions and not the full images as seen on the Epson Viewer.

Is there any way to set Camera Raw to open the images in the 4:3 format and without the in camera image size applied?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly which camera you're using?

Comment: Lightroom allows you to copy and paste settings between photos. Does Bridge allow the same thing? If so, then you can just remove the crop on one photo and copy the setting to the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to "Crop" in the Develop Module, you can choose between "As shot" which will give you the in-camera cropped version, or "Original" which will give you the full frame version of the RAW file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of Adobe Camera RAW. It appears that ACR reads the camera set cropping info and accepts that this is the ratio and limit of the pixels available.

I have done the same with Canon EOS cameras where it is possible to set the aspect ratio via a custom function. Once the images are imported to LR or PS there is no possibility to extend the cropping back to the original full image. However Canon's own software DPP does allow the crop to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following with exiftool:

- export the RAW image or
- remove the JPEG preview image or
- remove the cropping information

and load the resulting image with Camera Raw. (Make sure you make backups first in a separate directory!!)

ExifTool is avaliable [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), but any recent Linux distro has it. There is a [GUI](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/) available, too.

I can give you explicit steps if you are willing to share one of your incorrectly cropped photos.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to use ACR, but I believe if you use Lightroom you will have access to the whole image. If it doesn't appear by default you can adjust it with the crop tool.

If you have Lightroom set up to always write XMP files, maybe you can then open the file in ACR with your preferred crop.